# jQuery how to figure out if user inputed ' ' in text input area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

we have an `input type="text"` user prints into it some string. each time he inputs empty space char we want to  call some function. How to do such thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(input).keydown(function (e) {
    if ( e.which === 32 ) {
        // do your thing
    }
});
```

where `input` is a reference to your INPUT element.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uHpLg/

Comment: This is the right way to listen for spaces.  However, note this won't catch spaces pasted in, if that's a concern.

Comment: josh3736 is very much correct. While this technically is the right answer to the question, it is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sime Well, naturally, that's a possibilty. My personal experience though is that when people ask this type of question they want for example a username box not to contain spaces. Of course I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Check out jQuery's [keypress event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

```
$("#YourInputId").keypress(function() {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 32) { // 32 = space keycode
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Here's a web page that has a [list of javascript key codes](http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx).

Comment: jQuery already normalizes `e` (the [EventData object](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)); there's no need to do it yourself -- just use `e.which`.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a listener to the input onchange event.
Compare the current value to the last value and check is the new character is a space
If so, call a function.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the input text box  and bind to it a change listener
but this will work only when the box is unfocused and the new value is different than the old value

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#mytextbox').change(function(){

if ($(this).val() == ' ')
{

// do whatever u want 

}

});

});
```

but if u wanted something like autosuggestion (don't wait for user to unfocus the text input ) u can create ur own listener

is when the user focus the text box ,key press u check the pressed key and if it's is = " " do whatever u want 
and when the user unfocus the input , it stops checking it

```
$('#mytextbox').keypress(function (e){

if (e.keycode == 32 )
{

// do your code here 
}

});
```

for more info about keycodes : http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html
on keypress Jquery function documentation : http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: *(Edit: I see you edited your post right before I commented.)* Do not poll a HTML input to check for changes.  You have `keydown` events, use them!

Comment: i had problems first with keypress Vs keydown function till i got confused but yet u still right it's better than polling the input